# Starting QProcess and reading its output one line at a time

Tags: c++, qt

What would be the preferred way in Qt of reading a child process output one line at a time as it appears?

I tried connecting QProcess signal readyReadStandardOutput to the function that calls QProcess method readLine.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. What is the problem?

Comment: The function that would call readLine never got called. There are other functions connected to the same signal readyReadStandardOutput, but they shouldn't interfere with each other.

Comment: In other words, `readyReadStandardOutput` signal is not get emitted?

Comment: The signal gets emitted: another function (from another part of the same executable) is also connected to readyReadStandardOutput, receives it, and does readAllStandardOutput.

Comment: The thing is that once you read the output it will not be available anymore. What if you split the output you read (once) with `readAllStandardOutput` into separate lines and use them?

Answer (score 5):

The preferred way is the asynchronous way, using signals emitted by `QIODevice`. Your approach is correct. Make sure that you read all available lines within your slot:

```
process->setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
while (process->canReadLine()) {
   QString line = QString::fromLocal8bit(process->readLine());
   ...
}
```

Also remember that once you read something, it's not available to be read again. `QIODevice`'s signals need to be used with care - you can't connect an arbitrary number of consumers to the `readyRead` signal and perform the reading in each of them. It won't work the way you might have expected it to. If the first reader reads all of the data, the subsequent ones won't be able to read it again.

Answer (score 0):

Possible implementation:

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("/usr/bin/tegrastats");
QString line;
while(proc.waitForReadyRead())
{
    line = QString::fromUtf8(proc.readLine());
    qDebug() << line;
}
```